# javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException playing OGG files with javazoom

Tags: java, audio, ogg

I'm attempting to play OGG audio files using an answer to another question here: [Playing ogg files in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749909/playing-ogg-files-in-eclipse)

Using the [javazoom library](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) which I successfully downloaded and configured for my project, I am attempting to use the [xav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149528/xav)'s answer code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javazoom.spi.PropertiesContainer;

public class OGGPlayer {
public final String fileName;

public boolean mustStop = false;


public OGGPlayer(String pFileName) {
    fileName = pFileName;
}

public void play() throws Exception {
    mustStop = false;
    File file = new File(fileName);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    if (audioInputStream == null) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get audio input stream");
    }
    AudioFormat baseFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
        baseFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(),
        baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat.getSampleRate(), false);
    AudioInputStream decodedAudioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat,
        audioInputStream);
    if (!(decodedAudioInputStream instanceof PropertiesContainer)) {
        throw new Exception("Wrong PropertiesContainer instance");
    }

    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, decodedFormat);
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    sourceDataLine.open(decodedFormat);

    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[4096];

    // Start
    sourceDataLine.start();
    int nbReadBytes = 0;
    while (nbReadBytes != -1) {
        if (mustStop) {
            break;
        }
        nbReadBytes = decodedAudioInputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
        if (nbReadBytes != -1)
            sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, nbReadBytes);
    }

    // Stop
    sourceDataLine.drain();
    sourceDataLine.stop();
    sourceDataLine.close();
    decodedAudioInputStream.close();
    audioInputStream.close();
}

public void setMustStop(boolean pMustStop) {
    mustStop = pMustStop;
}

public void stop() {
    mustStop = true;
}

}
```

The code makes sense to me, but I am having trouble simply using it. I can't seem to get the class to read my OGG file, and I've modified it various ways in attempts to make this function. I read WAV files in this same project, reading the files completely successfully with

```
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("res/audio/" + fileName + ".wav"));
```

I've attempted variations of this, using the File class, reading as a resources, and I can successfully locate my OGG file in the project, but it keep throwing the exception

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL
```

This is my fourth or fifth attempt in getting audio to play non-WAV audio in this project. I tried playing MP3s with MediaPlayer and a few other ways, and this is my second method method of trying to play OGG files. I'm trying to play large, long music tracks as background, and I cannot run them as I do my other WAV sound effects due to file size.

Any help in playing these OGG files would be immensely appreciated. I feel so close to my goal with this attempt, it seems simple and solid, but it just refuses to read my files correctly. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The mp3spi code on the JavaZoom site reads MP3. You need the vorbisspi from the JavaZoom site and the associated JOrbis code.

Comment: Thank you. I am extremely disappointed in myself. This is a very clear case of working far too late and being very silly and moronic. Thank you for your aid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that will read mp3 and ogg files - it will play files with the vorbis format but not flac; so you have to put a check there - not all files ending with .ogg will be supported:

```
import javazoom.spi.vorbis.sampled.file.VorbisAudioFileReader;
import javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader;
import org.tritonus.share.sampled.file.TAudioFileReader;
import org.tritonus.sampled.file.AuAudioFileReader;

  AudioInputStream createOggMp3(File fileIn) throws IOException, Exception {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream=null;
    AudioFormat targetFormat=null;
    try {
      AudioInputStream in=null;
      if(fileIn.getName().endsWith(".ogg")) {
        VorbisAudioFileReader vb=new VorbisAudioFileReader();
        in=vb.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
      }
      else if(fileIn.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
        MpegAudioFileReader mp=new MpegAudioFileReader();
        in=mp.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
      }
      AudioFormat baseFormat=in.getFormat();
      targetFormat=new AudioFormat(
              AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
              baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
              16,
              baseFormat.getChannels(),
              baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
              baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
              false);
      audioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, in);
    }
    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException ue) { System.out.println("\nUnsupported Audio"); }
    return audioInputStream;
  }
```

It returns you an audio input stream which you can use as follows:

```
if(fileIn.getName().endsWith(".ogg") || fileIn.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
  audioInputStream=createOggMp3(fileIn);
}
else { // wav
    audioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
  }
```

Your decoded audio format is

```
decodedFormat=audioInputStream.getFormat();
```

and then you can continue with your SourceDataline.